# Is it possible to avoid iframe generation in ASP .NET Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp menu in masterpage.master to switch between pages in an intranet site. It is causing layout issues in IE8, since it generates iframe which is shrinked to a default size. The iframe does not stretch to remaining space of the container.

Is there a way to avoid iframe generation when using asp menu in masterpage.master files?

EDIT : It seems that using asp:Content and asp:ContentPlaceHolder is the one which is causing iframe to be generated. (I use asp:ContentPlaceHolder in matserpage.master and asp:Content in the actual asp .net page)

Comment: `Masterpages` in ASP.NET do **not** generate `iFrames`. This is different (custom?) behaviour. You should dump some relevant code here ;)

Comment: I agree with @Caspar, master pages don't automatically cause iframes. You write the HTML you want above and below all the other pages. You can choose to put it in an iframe, or do something else. Code from the master page's .master file would help.

Answer (score 1):

The regular menu creates table-based menus.  I haven't seen iframes.  Either way, .NET 4 adds the [RenderingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.renderingmode.aspx) property which lets you use list-based menus.  This should give you the flexibility you want in combination with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have ever seen iFrame generation with a menu in ASP.NET. Regardless, if you want full control, consider the CSS Friendly adapters and use it to create a CSS driven menu rather than the table driven mess the control creates by default. You can download from http://www.asp.net.